# Error 500 Internal Server vps CentOs permisos usuarios grupo Sudoers

Tags: centos

El problema que tengo actualmente es que no me permite leer nada del servidor en la web porque accidentalmente cambie permisos de algunos archivos, me comentaron que se deben asociar al grupo de `sudoers` pero no sé como hacerlo, necesito esto urgente, tengo accesos `SSH` con el user `ROOT` y acceso a la administración del servidor a través de web

```
   sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

Me sale ese aviso cuando intento hacer sudo con un usuario normal.

Comment: ¿Qué usuario era el dueño de los archivos y qué permisos tenían antes? ¿Podrías probar a subir un archivo para ver qué permisos por defecto tiene? ¿Usas apache con el usuario por defecto `www-data`?

Comment: Es que eso precisamento lo que necesito saber cuales son los permisos por defecto, los propietarios por defecto y los grupos por defecto, los reemplzae por accidente, logre volver a tener acceso pero le di permisos que no tenia antes

Comment: Osea requiero saber cuales son los usuarios, grupos y propietarios de archivos por defecto al montar un servidor VPS, ya que olvide lo sagrado, hacer respaldo de todo...XD

Comment: Al montar un servidor VPS los permisos por defecto son los que configures. Por norma general en Linux el umask es 0755, pero se puede cambiar. Da permisos al directorio para que todos escriban: `chmod a+w .` y luego sube un archivo y crea un directorio. Se crearán con el usuario y permisos por defecto.